# Lower Limit < A < Upper Limit

Tags: swift, boolean, xcode6, boolean-expression

I need to know if something is between two limits, but I keep getting the same 2 errors in playground and I can't seem to find a solution on the web.  Any idea how to do this in Swift?

```
var upperLimit = 20
var a = 10
var lowerlimit = 5

if a > lowerlimit < upperLimit{      
println(a)
}


if  lowerlimit < a < upperLimit{
println(a)
}
```

Both of these methods give the same (2) error messages:

---> ! Non-associative operator is adjacent to operator of same precedence

--> Cannot invoke '<'with an argument of list type '($t4, @Ivalue Int)'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a valid way to make the comparison. You need to check against the bounds with two comparisons:

```
if a > lowerlimit && a < upperLimit {
    println(a)
}
```

Although I prefer this way using pattern recognition on a range.

```
if lowerlimit..<upperLimit ~= a {
    println(a)
}
```

Note that the pattern recognition way requires the lower bound to be inclusive, so you'd need to increase the lowerLimit variable by one.